# Get attached property instance from dependency property change callback

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, attached-properties

Is there anyway of getting the instance of an attached property from a property change callback sitting on the attached property type?

In other words, if you have:

```
public class MyAttachedPropertyClass
{
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "My", typeof(int), typeof(MyAttachedPropertyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, OnMyPropertyChanged));

 private static void OnMyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      //TODO: access instance of MyAttachedPropertyClass
    }
}
```

I need to access the instance of MyAttachedPropertyClass so that I can set the value of another property sitting on the type.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to do. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I have an instance based field on MyAttachedPropertyClass, I need to set the value of that field in OnMyPropertyChanged to the value of e.NewValue which is an integer.  Because OnMyPropertyChanged is static, I can't access this instance field in a static context.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, or what you want to do, but if you just need the object instance which the property change is happening on (my best guess of what you mean so far), that is your 'DependencyObject d' parameter.

Comment: I think I found your answer in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453146/getting-this-pointer-inside-dependency-property-changed-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in my experience at least, the type that attached properties are owned by is static. When not static, when it comes to setting an attached property, no instance of the owning type is instantiated. If that's what you really want, you're going to have to do a bit more work.

Essentially, you're going to need to instantiate the instance at some point yourself and then make it accessible in your `OnMyPropertyChanged`, likely through some kind of static state.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but as an alternative, you are able to set other attached properties on your `DependencyObject` "`d`" in `OnMyPropertyChanged`. So, if there's some kind of state you want to keep around you could put it in annother attached property.

It occurs to me, at this point, that `MyAttachedPropertyClass` may be a control of sorts that uses attached properties like the `Grid` or `DockPanel`. In that case, `MyAttachedPropertyClass` may be a parent of the `DependencyObject` "`d`" and you can access it using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class.

At this point, I'm just shooting in the dark with answers. If you have any more details about what you're trying to do, I may be able to help you further.